# set method is not working

Tags: java, date, methods

I was doing one of my projects and couldn't really work my set method. And my set constructor was not working. I am new in class and need help. it will be a great help if you guys help me thank you.

> My Class is:

```
public class date {
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
public date () 
{
    day     = 1;
    month   = 1;
    year    = 1900;

}
```

I set up the constructor hear this is how it goes:

```
// set constructor
public date (int a,int b,int c) //(day,month,year)
{

    if (a <1)
    {
        day     = 1;
        a       = day;
    }
    if (b<1)
    {
        month   = 1;
        b       = month;
    }
    if (c<1900)
    {
        year    = 1900;
        c       = year;
    }
    else
    {
        a   = day;
        b   = month;
        c   = year;
    }
}
```

this is where I started to set the veribals as an mutators

```
// set date
public void setDay (int a)
{
    if (a <1)
    {
        day = 1;
        a   = day;
    }
    else
        a   = day;
}
// set month
public void setMonth (int a)
{
    if (a <1)
    {
        month   = 1;
        a       = month;
    }
    else
        a       = month;
}
// set year
public void setYear (int a)
{
    if (a <1990)
    {
        year    = 1990;
        a       =   year;
    }
    else
        a       = year;
}
```

And this is where I started to write my accessories

```
//Accsessors
public int getDay ()
{
    return day;
}
public int getMonth ()
{
    return month;
}
public int getYear ()
{
    return year;
}



}
```

> my main class is:

```
public class checkDate {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    date year1 = new date();
    date year2 = new date (21,3,1995);

    year1.setDay(13);
    year1.setMonth(12);
    year1.setYear(2010);

    System.out.println(year1.getDay());
    System.out.println(year1.getYear());
    System.out.println(year2.getYear());
   }

 }
```

> Output is:

1

1900

0

I tried checking everything I even tried to change the value but nothing works only thing I get is 1 and 1900

Comment: `a   = day;` - what does this achieve?

Comment: I would recommend you reading tutorial about Java classes, getter and setters and reading about conditional statements.

Comment: Your setters will accept numbers lower than 1 and 1900 respectively. You should rewrite it to accept any number value.

Comment: Your code above indicates you need to go over some more tutorials on Java to get up to speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the assignment statements are backwards. The expression on the right of the equals is assigned to the variable on the left. Here is what they should look like instead:

```
public date(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a < 1)
        a = 1;
    if (b < 1)
        b = 1;
    if (c < 1900)
        c = 1900;
    day = a;
    month = b;
    year = c;
}
```

The setters have a similar problem. Don't assign to the parameter, assign to the instance variable.

```
public void setDay(int a) {
    if (a < 1)
        a = 1;
    day = a;
}
public void setMonth(int a) {
    if (a < 1)
        a = 1;
    month = a;
}
public void setYear(int a) {
    if (a < 1990)
        a = 1990;
    year = a;
}
```

**Note**: For more readable code, use better parameter names. Instead of reusing `a`, perhaps you should use `d`, `m` or `y` depending on the setter. Also, typical Java naming conventions always capitalize the first letter of class names, so you should use `Date` instead of `date`.

Comment: OMG thank you soo much now it work. thank you thank you are a live saver.

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting the day and month when they are less than 1, and the year when it's less than 1990. You should probably flip those "<" into ">".

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your variable assignments.
You could condense your code like this, by using the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

```
public class Date{

  private int day;
  private int month;
  private int year;

  public Date(int d, int m, int y){
    day = d<1 ? 1 : d;
    month = m<1||m>12 ? 1 : m;
    year = y<1900 ? 1990 : y;
  }

  public int getDay(){
    return day;
  }
  ...
  public void setDay(int d){
    day = d<1 ? 1 : d;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: While correct, a ternary operator is a bit much for a newbie programmer.